# Angular 7: trying to delay router.navigate with setTimeout not working

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-universal, angular7

I'm having an issue with my sign in handler redirecting to a page before the cookie with the user token is written. As a workaround, I tried adding a delay before the navigation, but it isn't working.

Why is the navigation happening before the timeout delay? (This is Angular 7 Universal.) I also tried setting the token in the delay function, but it didn't make a difference.

```
signInSuccessHandler() {
...
   const token = this.getToken();
        this.setToken(access_token);
        setTimeout(() => { this.delayNavigation(); }, 1000);
  }

  delayNavigation() {
    this._zone.run(() => this.router.navigate(['/people']));
  }
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not waiting for the timeout?

Comment: you can make `this.setToken(access_toke)` return a promise, and wait until it resolves, after that you would do a redirect.

Comment: it's not the answer, but Why not navigate after setToken?. If your setToken return an observable -you can simple use return Observable.of(true)- you can redirect in subscribe. If is more comples your setToken, after SetToken emit a value observables and subscribe to the Observable. The "angular way" is NOT wait a time and expect the given time was enought to the things happens

Comment: @YuriyKravets that’s a great idea. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the replies. I found the underlying cause, so I don't need the workaround anymore.

A service was being instantiated before the token was available. The timeout didn't help because the issue had already happened.